# Is there a way to retain certain files during a composer update or install?

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm using a package in my Laravel application that doesn't have support for Laravel out of the box, so I added a Facade and Service Provider to it myself. Both of those files are checked into my repo (specified in .gitignore using the ! prefix). However, when composer updates a package it completely removes it first, and this is preventing automatic deployment with platforms like Codeship.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fork the package, create a custom repo with your changes - then include that in your `composer.json`.

```
{
    "repositories": [ {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/YourGithubUsername/PackageName"
         }
    }],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "OriginalVendor/PackageName": "1.0.*"
    },
}
```

That way you can pull your custom changes in anytime, without having to commit it to your specific project.

You can read more about forking and loading packages here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs

Answer (score 1):

Never change the code of packages! In fact, never touch the `vendor` directory.

You should either [fork] the repository and add your code (see @TheShiftExchange's answer)

Or add the Facade and the ServiceProvider in **your namespace**.

Comment: Thanks, I've taken the fork approach and changed .gitignore back.